# How is BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

The way to cancel a BackgroundWorker's operation is to call `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()`:

```
// RUNNING IN UI THREAD
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}
```

In a BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler, we check `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending`:

```
// RUNNING IN WORKER THREAD
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending) {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The above idea is all over the web, including on [the MSDN page for BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker).

Now, my question is this:  How on earth is this thread-safe?

I've looked at the BackgroundWorker class in ILSpy — `CancelAsync()` simply sets cancellationPending to true without using a memory barrier, and `CancellationPending` simply returns cancellationPending without using a memory barrier.

According to [this Jon Skeet page](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/volatility.shtml), the above is *not* thread-safe.  But [the documentation for BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) says, "This property is meant for use by the worker thread, which should periodically check CancellationPending and abort the background operation when it is set to true."

What's going on here?  Is it thread-safe or not?

Comment: Note that Jon Skeets example uses a static var, not a property. I think the property prevents caching of the value and that makes it completely thread-safe.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I didn't consider that a property might be different.  I wonder whether that is documented anywhere…

Comment: Then again, `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()` sets the field, not the property, to true, so I guess there could be a problem of writing only to the cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is thread-safe.
The code

```
  while (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
```

is reading a property and the compiler knows it can't cache the result.

And since in the normal framework every Write is the same as VolatileWrite, the CancelAsync() method can just set a field.

Answer (score 13):

It is because BackgroundWorker inherits from Component which inherits from MarshalByRefObject.  An MBRO object may reside on another machine or in another process or appdomain.  That works by having the object impersonated by a proxy that has all of the exact same properties and methods but whose implementations marshal the call across the wire.

One side effect of that is that the jitter cannot inline methods and properties, that would break the proxy.  Which also prevents any optimizations from being made that stores the field value in a cpu register.  Just like volatile does.

Comment: My understanding was that question asks specifically about backing field of the CancellationPending, not about the property itself (the property is a feature of the language and is just a method from CLR standpoint). So what prevents backing field from being cached by reading thread?

Comment: @Dmitry - The fact that it is private (cancellationPending, lower case first letter).  Client code *has* to use the property.

Comment: As a consultation do you think in this case the scenario I described in my answer will not happen even on a weak memory models?

Comment: @Hans: One of us misunderstands the original question. The value returned from CancellationPending may be stale because the backing field can be cached. The only thing that CancellationPending property does it just reads the value from the backing field. And the point of the question is that this read may be accessing CPU cache, not main memory. This is not about the client code at all.

Comment: @Jalal - they have a memory update ordering problem.  There's however only one field involved here.  So no.  This code runs on a Titanium.

Comment: @Dmitry - stale doesn't matter, it will only take the thread a while to see the update.  Thus the remark about MRE.  It cannot be stale forever, the cache does update.  The danger scenario that *volatile* protects against is the x86 jitter generating code to store the value of a field in a register.  Not an issue because this is accessed through a property getter.

Comment: @Hans: Just want to clarify your answer. If we don't take client code into account. BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending implementation is incorrect because it reads backing field value from potentially cached location. So the updates to the field will not be visible to it immediately. The correct implementation would read the most up to date value. Is this correct? If it is, why can't this be fixed by making backing field volatile?

Comment: @Dmitry - declaring it volatile makes no difference, it is already treated volatile.

Comment: @Hans: There seem to be no barrier, no lock, no explicit VolatileRead. What makes this backing field being treated as volatile?

Comment: @Dmitry - I explained that in my answer.  Sorry that I couldn't explain it well enough, the subject of *volatile* is fairly impenetrable until you grok machine code and why CPU registers matter.

Answer (score 1):

Question can be interpreted in two ways:

1) Is BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending **implementation** correct?

It is not correct because it may result in cancellation request being unnoticed. The implementation uses ordinary read from the backing field. If this backing field is updated by other threads then the update may be invisible to the reading code. This is what implementation looks like:

```
// non volatile variable:
private Boolean cancellationPending;

public Boolean CancellationPending {
    get {
        // ordinary read:
        return cancellationPending;
    }
}
```

The correct implementation would try to read the most up to date value. This can be achieved by declaring backing field 'volatile', using memory barrier or lock. There are probably other options and some of them are better than the others but is up to the team that owns 'BackgroundWorker' class.

2) Is code that **uses** BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending correct?

```
while (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending) {
    DoSomething();
}
```

This code is correct. The loop will spin until CancellationPending returns 'true'. Keeping in mind that C# properties is just a syntax sugar for CLR methods. At the IL level this is just another method that will look like "get_CancellationPending". Method return values are not cached by calling code (probably because figuring whether method has side effects is too hard).

Answer (score 0):

A good point and a very fair doubt. It sounds like not thread safe. I think MSDN also has the same doubt and that's why this is there under [BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync).

**Caution**

> Be aware that your code in the DoWork event handler may finish its
>   work as a cancellation request is being made, and your polling loop
>   may miss CancellationPending being set to true. In this case, the
>   Cancelled flag of System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs in
>   your RunWorkerCompleted event handler will not be set to true, even
>   though a cancellation request was made. This situation is called a
>   race condition and is a common concern in multithreaded programming.
>   For more information about multithreading design issues, see Managed
>   Threading Best Practices.

I am not sure about BackgroundWorker class implementation. Looking at how it is using [BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) property internally is important in this case.

Comment: I see, but my main worry is that `backgroundWorker.CancellationPending`, in backgroundWorker_DoWork, may never evaluate to true, even if `backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();` has been called, because of caching.  If so, RunWorkerCompleted event will never be raised anyway.

Comment: This is not what OP asked. The problem you are describing is caused by the fact that the worker thread may **end** before it has the chance to set the cancelled flag in event's args. OP is asking whether it is safe to assume that a different thread can read the current value of the flag after it has been set.