# backgroundworker: How do I execute a method and support canceling _DoWork?

Tags: .net, backgroundworker

I have [referred to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28VS.95%29.aspx) and found out that it is quite easy to cancel a BackgroundWorker's _DoWork(), by trigger an event.

I would like to know how to cancel _DoWork() while performing work in another method that I've called within _DoWork().

Is this possible?

http://pastebin.com/wHrrBWKZ

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: You may also be interested in reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966573/how-is-backgroundworker-cancellationpending-thread-safe/6967720#6967720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BackgroundWorker` sample [here](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html) shows how to do it.

In summary:

- When you create the `BackgroundWorker`, set `WorkerSupportsCancellation`.
- In your `DoWork` handler, periodically check `CancellationPending`. If it is true, then set `DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel` to true and return from `DoWork`.
- To cancel the task, call `CancelAsync`.
- To detect the task has been cancelled, observe `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled`.

To do this from within another method, that method must have the `BackgroundWorker` instance and the `DoWorkEventArgs` instance passed to it.

Comment: I'll pass those objects, and raise the events from them!  Thanks!