# background worker dispose vs thread.abort

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
bg = new BackgroundWorker();
bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
bg.RunWorkerAsync();

void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
    }
}

bg.DoWork -= new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
bg.Dispose();
```

After calling this, I see that `BackgroundWorker` is still working. But instead of `BackgroundWorker`, if I use `Thread` and call `Abort()` then it is not working. Why is that so?

Comment: When you say that it is not working, what do you mean? Are you trying to cancel the task before it finishes or are you trying to reuse the backgrounderworker/thread once the task has completed?

Comment: I mean I could end thread succesfully but while(true) code block is not stopped after calling dispose of backgroundworker.

Comment: Dispose will free any native components. The while loop is not native thus is still running

Comment: Calling `.Dispose();` on the backgroundworker is not enough to cancel the process. dlatikay explains this in his answer below. If you want to actually cancel the task given to the background worker, [this link on backgroundworker vs task.run](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-4.html) may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually, you are assigning an infinite task to your `BackgroundWorker` (this is because `while (true)` must implement an explicit command that stops the infinite loop like a `break` statement or a `return` statement).

Once the method handler is fired (through the invocation of `bg.RunWorkerAsync()`), it will keep on running no matter what you do.

Unsubscribing the event handler will not stop it, because somewhere over the rainbow the show must go on.

Disposing the `BackgroundWorker` instance will not stop it either. The `BackgroundWorker` class derives from `Component` (which implements the `IDisposable` interface) and inherits the `Dispose()` method, but without overriding it. In its base implementation, `Component.Dispose()` only grants that the component is removed from the `components` collection and the `Disposed` event is raised... but the thread being created doesn't get killed.

Keeping your design as it currently is, the only way you can stop the `BackgroundWorker` is settings its `WorkerSupportsCancellation` property to true upon creation:

```
bg = new BackgroundWorker();
bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

and then calling:

```
bg.CancelAsync();
```

when needed. Avoid the `Thread.Abort()` approach, it's unsafe.

Comment: I tried this but it did not stop while(true) execution.

Comment: Because you have to implement a check on `CancellationPending` within the event handler: `void bg_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!bg.CancellationPending)
        DoSomething();
}`

Comment: For more infos, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966573/how-is-backgroundworker-cancellationpending-thread-safe

Answer (score 2):

`RunWorkerAsync` spawns a thread. Calling `Abort()` deliberately terminates this thread, while `Dispose()` disposes of the background worker instance. The worker thread is not notified from this disposal and will happily continue execution.

In fact, `BackgroundWorker` is disposable just because it [inherits from `Component`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs,20). The dispose logic of `Component` takes care of the container and event handler binding, but `BackgroundWorker` itself has nothing to clean up when disposed.

Comment: The only way to stop backgroundworker execution in this case, just change the bool to false right ?

Comment: afaik you call `CancelAsync`, and poll for `CancellationPending` in the worker method, [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `BackgroundWorker` has no code to abort the thread (you can check the code [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs,85d60b0d93a826fa)). Instead of killing the thread, you should cancel the background job properly. For instance,

```
while (!BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
{
    label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
}
```